# PHP create thumbnail from uploaded file and moving to server

Tags: php

I have encountered a problem with creating a thumbnail from an uploaded image file, then to upload it to the server.

As of now, I have a function that creates the thumbnail, saves it as a temp and returns it to the caller.

Then what I try to do, is upload that created thumb image with move_uploaded_file(tempthumb, path);

Here is the createThumb function and the caller:

```
function createThumb( $image, $thumbWidth )
{
  // load image and get image size
  $img = imagecreatefromjpeg( "{$image}" );
  $width = imagesx( $img );
  $height = imagesy( $img );

  // calculate thumbnail size
  $new_width = $thumbWidth;
  $new_height = floor( $height * ( $thumbWidth / $width ) );

  // create a new temporary image
  $tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor( $new_width, $new_height );

  // copy and resize old image into new image 
  imagecopyresized( $tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

  return $tmp_img;

}

return $tmp_img; // Here I return the new image. Is this the proper way to get a binary image back??
```

Here is the caller:

```
$thumb = createThumb($_FILES['propform-previmg']['tmp_name'], $max_previmg_width); 
        $filenamepath = $src_dir . '/thumb/' . $_FILES['propform-previmg']['name'];
        if ( !move_uploaded_file($thumb, $filenamepath ))
            echo "Error moving file {$filenamepath}";
```

I tried to just upload the uploaded file directly without trying to make a thumbnail first, and that worked fine. So I guess there is some error with the variable I return from the createThumb function, but I can't figure out exactly what.

Also, I need to do the upload from the caller code, and not inside the createThumb function with imagejpeg(file, path).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First line from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php):

> This function checks to ensure that the file designated by filename is a valid upload file (**meaning that it was uploaded via PHP's HTTP POST upload mechanism**). If the file is valid, it will be moved to the filename given by destination.

Your thumbnail wasn't uploaded, it even isn't a file yet, but just an image resource. To write the image, call something like `imagejpeg($resource, $filename)` to write it to the path specified in `$filename`.

Comment: So the resource I get back from the createThumb() function should be renamed to the uploaded file name? I don't fully understand I'm afraid. Thank you for the answer

Comment: In the context of the code, you mean something like this?

    rename($thumb, $_FILES['propform-previmg']['tmp_name']);  Before doing the move?

Comment: Your solution along with another fixed the problem! The other solution was to install the GD lib on the server, hehe.

Thanks!